# Access restriction on MediaWiki: make pages private until approved

Tags: mediawiki, access-rights, mediawiki-extensions

I am stuck over an access right situation,

What I Want is:

I have users creating articles/pages on MediaWiki, I have restricted it over registered/autoconfirmed users to only, But now the requirement is, that, Only an article can be displayed to anyone other than , creator or sysop only after the sysop approves that page/article. till then only the creator or sysop can edit that article.

I have tried FlaggedRevs extension, and several other small restrictions, but couldn't get exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Just to clarfy: You want the functionality of Flagged Revs, but with the addition that new pages are not visible for non syops until approved?

Comment: Yeah, Kind of that, But I found the extension to do what I want, "its called, Approved Revs" After a little bit of hacking around I got what I wanted. Thanks for replying anyway. I will close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers, there is an extension called "Approved Revs". With few options set and some messing around, I have done it.