# Notify on creation of pages in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

My question is similar to one from 4 years ago located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209929/access-restriction-on-mediawiki-make-pages-private-until-approved) however that was never fully answered.

I would like to have it so that everytime a new page is created the Administrator user group is notified. Preferably by email and by something similar to how it is in [Moderation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Moderation)

I do **NOT** want every edit having to be approved as most extensions provide.

It seems to me that [Moderation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Moderation) or [ApproveRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ApprovedRevs) might work but I can't figure out how.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a [mcve] with your post.

Comment: If you want to write an extension for this (it is fairly easy) you can use https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/project/view/137/ or https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org/ to ask for help (feel free to ping me there).

Comment: @Tgr Sounds good! I did try to make an extension but quickly got lost. I might take you up on that offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extension:EditNotify](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EditNotify) seems to be the best solution I have been able to find, however not ideal because you have to add each user manually instead of by user rights.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [EmailAllChanges](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailAllChanges) which works great, but still needed to be configures per users in his preference.

As i saw (now) its been archived month ago (the others extensions are not maintained as well [as you can check at github]).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe EditNotify is a better solution in this case.